# how console.log in tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I have such test and i want see console.log in my terminal. how i can got it? for example console.log(rafSpy). Сan you do so at all?

```
it("should not render coin if move time ended", () => {
            const rafSpy = jest.spyOn(window, "requestAnimationFrame");
            console.log(rafSpy)
            let rafCb;
            rafSpy.mockImplementation(cb => rafCb = cb);
            const perfSpy = jest.spyOn(performance, "now");
            perfSpy.mockReturnValue(0);

            const subject = mount(<CoinsAndStars stars={true} coins={true} DeviceSupport={DeviceSupport} />);
            ctxMock.ellipse = jest.fn();
            subject.instance().coins[0].moveTime = 2;
            subject.instance().coins[0].lifeTime = 1.5;
            const visibleCoinCount = COIN_COUNT - 1;
            const ellipseDrawCountInOneFrameRender =
                ((COIN_WIDTH * 2) / EDGE_SEGMENT_STEP + 1)
                * visibleCoinCount
                + visibleCoinCount;
            // 1.5sec of lifet will be increased by 0.6ms
            rafCb(600);
            expect(subject.instance().coins[0].lifeTime).toBeGreaterThan(2);
            expect(ctxMock.ellipse).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(ellipseDrawCountInOneFrameRender);
            rafSpy.mockRestore();
            perfSpy.mockRestore();
        });
```

Comment: you can press f12 if you are using chrome and see your values logged in the console window from the developer tools. Most browsers have developer tools. Not so much a terminal window though..

Comment: You can't have `window` global in browserless (by it's nature) Enzyme test. If your component's code requires it and its methods, you should create it by mocking.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to accomplish may need a work-around seeing as how the Web API, [Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console), as used in your code, may only serve as a functional interface from Browser-to-Browser.

One suggestion that I have is to use an Interactive Developer Environment(IDE) to find a similar work-flow. An IDE like [C9.io](https://c9.io), or [StackBlitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/) may help you find the ease-of-use work-flow you are looking for, allowing you to partition your cloud work space in a completely customize-able manner. Drag and drop your Preview tab, your Terminal tab, or your script tags wherever you find it more convenient, and most importantly, get to the coding without all of the hassle!